# How to separate Application Insights Live Streams by server?

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have setup Application Insights on several of my server environments. I have pointed several different servers to the same Azure resource and for the most part this has worked out very well. You can split up all of the telemetry data by server and everything is nicely in one place.

My main issue is that I can't see how to filter Application Insights Live Streams based on server. There is a small button-looking thing that says "3 Servers" on the Live Stream page but it isn't actually a button. I can't seem to find a way to only see one which is what I would like to do. Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you!

Comment: i'm *pretty* sure you can't do this at the current time.  I think the livestream is only getting the count from the data that's coming in, so that's why it shows you the count.  i'm pretty sure that it doesn't actually get the names of the servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: As of Dec, 7 2016 you should be able to see a list of servers, sort by different metrics and drill down into instance view by clicking on one of them. In instance view both charts and sample failures will show data from selected instance.

============ OLD =============

Unfortunately it is not supported today.

But Server/Instance View is one of the most asked features and it solely occupies #1 place on our radar.

Comment: Thank you so much! So for right now if I want to get a separate Live Stream for each server, should I create separate AI resources and just add each server to each one?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, at the moment this is the only workaround. Not a great one and in many cases unfeasible. Will fix that :)

Comment: @LeftOnTheMoon, please let us know if new Servers feature doesn't answer original question. Or if you have any other feedback! =)